# Facebook Login: URL isn't included in the app's domains! I get error > Catchable fatal error in FacebookClient.php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

I know many such questions have already been asked tried a lot then after posting the question. I`ll start from beginning: 
Few days ago I tried to sing in with my facebook user I get message from facebook: „URL isn't included in the app's domains!“ I solved it by adding URL in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/.../fb-login/settings/  Valid OAuth redirect URIs.

**The problems that I have now is when user tries to login with facebook account see this error**
`Catchable fatal error: Argument 4 passed to Facebook\FacebookResponse::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/sportobatai/public_html/TOTASPORT/facebook-php-sdk/FacebookClient.php on line 225 and defined in /home/sportobatai/public_html/TOTASPORT/facebook-php-sdk/FacebookResponse.php on line 75`

**1. The link "Login with facebook"** 
https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=829ee1c76aa23a76223dd500d49289b6&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.0.0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftotasport.com%2F&scope=email

**2. The link when user sings with facebook account:**
[http://totasport.com/?code=AQBVHr63oHzB2nYdDQMet0NrpW7QJ_LEdzRfApdGnyywLgzwT-nv8a3pfFmKPSGHYkjzsjt9D0y74nr-GWyLMSbPPC_E8PKYYXG7G1-U8cn-KDPd3dd3Rw-Ysot8s8tq7MlQ6OIVk-YFbN7hc5SM_-K9EbBb0ofpl5ypfRbIUvI3c-XxVoMKxIWRYf1PR9l5CPWNLWjbmx2ceADdS5cxvrx2gEK-5CR1ZB77y-YRCEB4yNhzcsWJKPc5xWvh2e4ss8S_8CHvfvMF7JPK7mB8YrFdB0LK69adOMYjUF76fGqpnj2EybizYvo4GpsjkqANrC4&state=829ee1c76aa23a76223dd500d49289b6#*=*](http://totasport.com/?code=AQBVHr63oHzB2nYdDQMet0NrpW7QJ_LEdzRfApdGnyywLgzwT-nv8a3pfFmKPSGHYkjzsjt9D0y74nr-GWyLMSbPPC_E8PKYYXG7G1-U8cn-KDPd3dd3Rw-Ysot8s8tq7MlQ6OIVk-YFbN7hc5SM_-K9EbBb0ofpl5ypfRbIUvI3c-XxVoMKxIWRYf1PR9l5CPWNLWjbmx2ceADdS5cxvrx2gEK-5CR1ZB77y-YRCEB4yNhzcsWJKPc5xWvh2e4ss8S_8CHvfvMF7JPK7mB8YrFdB0LK69adOMYjUF76fGqpnj2EybizYvo4GpsjkqANrC4&state=829ee1c76aa23a76223dd500d49289b6#_=_)

The error appears.

**3. The Code what I used to make a login with Facebook:**
https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-facebook-using-php/

**4. Screens from developers.facebook.com:**
[> facebook app settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV3NQ.png)
[> facebook login settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDVyX.png)

**5. FacebookClient.php**

```html
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2014 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * You are hereby granted a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free license to
 * use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in source code or binary
 * form for use in connection with the web services and APIs provided by
 * Facebook.
 *
 * As with any software that integrates with the Facebook platform, your use
 * of this software is subject to the Facebook Developer Principles and
 * Policies [http://developers.facebook.com/policy/]. This copyright notice
 * shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
 * THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
 * DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */
namespace Facebook;

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpClientInterface;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookStreamHttpClient;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

/**
 * Class FacebookClient
 *
 * @package Facebook
 */
class FacebookClient
{
    /**
     * @const string Production Graph API URL.
     */
    const BASE_GRAPH_URL = 'https://graph.facebook.com';

    /**
     * @const string Graph API URL for video uploads.
     */
    const BASE_GRAPH_VIDEO_URL = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com';

    /**
     * @const string Beta Graph API URL.
     */
    const BASE_GRAPH_URL_BETA = 'https://graph.beta.facebook.com';

    /**
     * @const string Beta Graph API URL for video uploads.
     */
    const BASE_GRAPH_VIDEO_URL_BETA = 'https://graph-video.beta.facebook.com';

    /**
     * @const int The timeout in seconds for a normal request.
     */
    const DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 60;

    /**
     * @const int The timeout in seconds for a request that contains file uploads.
     */
    const DEFAULT_FILE_UPLOAD_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 3600;

    /**
     * @const int The timeout in seconds for a request that contains video uploads.
     */
    const DEFAULT_VIDEO_UPLOAD_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 7200;

    /**
     * @var bool Toggle to use Graph beta url.
     */
    protected $enableBetaMode = false;

    /**
     * @var FacebookHttpClientInterface HTTP client handler.
     */
    protected $httpClientHandler;

    /**
     * @var int The number of calls that have been made to Graph.
     */
    public static $requestCount = 0;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new FacebookClient object.
     *
     * @param FacebookHttpClientInterface|null $httpClientHandler
     * @param boolean                          $enableBeta
     */
    public function __construct(FacebookHttpClientInterface $httpClientHandler = null, $enableBeta = false)
    {
        $this->httpClientHandler = $httpClientHandler ?: $this->detectHttpClientHandler();
        $this->enableBetaMode = $enableBeta;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the HTTP client handler.
     *
     * @param FacebookHttpClientInterface $httpClientHandler
     */
    public function setHttpClientHandler(FacebookHttpClientInterface $httpClientHandler)
    {
        $this->httpClientHandler = $httpClientHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the HTTP client handler.
     *
     * @return FacebookHttpClientInterface
     */
    public function getHttpClientHandler()
    {
        return $this->httpClientHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Detects which HTTP client handler to use.
     *
     * @return FacebookHttpClientInterface
     */
    public function detectHttpClientHandler()
    {
        return function_exists('curl_init') ? new FacebookCurlHttpClient() : new FacebookStreamHttpClient();
    }

    /**
     * Toggle beta mode.
     *
     * @param boolean $betaMode
     */
    public function enableBetaMode($betaMode = true)
    {
        $this->enableBetaMode = $betaMode;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the base Graph URL.
     *
     * @param boolean $postToVideoUrl Post to the video API if videos are being uploaded.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseGraphUrl($postToVideoUrl = false)
    {
        if ($postToVideoUrl) {
            return $this->enableBetaMode ? static::BASE_GRAPH_VIDEO_URL_BETA : static::BASE_GRAPH_VIDEO_URL;
        }

        return $this->enableBetaMode ? static::BASE_GRAPH_URL_BETA : static::BASE_GRAPH_URL;
    }

    /**
     * Prepares the request for sending to the client handler.
     *
     * @param FacebookRequest $request
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareRequestMessage(FacebookRequest $request)
    {
        $postToVideoUrl = $request->containsVideoUploads();
        $url = $this->getBaseGraphUrl($postToVideoUrl) . $request->getUrl();

        // If we're sending files they should be sent as multipart/form-data
        if ($request->containsFileUploads()) {
            $requestBody = $request->getMultipartBody();
            $request->setHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $requestBody->getBoundary(),
            ]);
        } else {
            $requestBody = $request->getUrlEncodedBody();
            $request->setHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            ]);
        }

        return [
            $url,
            $request->getMethod(),
            $request->getHeaders(),
            $requestBody->getBody(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Makes the request to Graph and returns the result.
     *
     * @param FacebookRequest $request
     *
     * @return FacebookResponse
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     */
    public function sendRequest(FacebookRequest $request)
    {
        if (get_class($request) === 'FacebookRequest') {
            $request->validateAccessToken();
        }

        list($url, $method, $headers, $body) = $this->prepareRequestMessage($request);

        // Since file uploads can take a while, we need to give more time for uploads
        $timeOut = static::DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT;
        if ($request->containsFileUploads()) {
            $timeOut = static::DEFAULT_FILE_UPLOAD_REQUEST_TIMEOUT;
        } elseif ($request->containsVideoUploads()) {
            $timeOut = static::DEFAULT_VIDEO_UPLOAD_REQUEST_TIMEOUT;
        }

        // Should throw `FacebookSDKException` exception on HTTP client error.
        // Don't catch to allow it to bubble up.
        $rawResponse = $this->httpClientHandler->send($url, $method, $body, $headers, $timeOut);

        static::$requestCount++;

        $returnResponse = new FacebookResponse(
            $request,
            $rawResponse->getBody(),
            $rawResponse->getHttpResponseCode(),
            $rawResponse->getHeaders()
        );

        if ($returnResponse->isError()) {
            throw $returnResponse->getThrownException();
        }

        return $returnResponse;
    }

    /**
     * Makes a batched request to Graph and returns the result.
     *
     * @param FacebookBatchRequest $request
     *
     * @return FacebookBatchResponse
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     */
    public function sendBatchRequest(FacebookBatchRequest $request)
    {
        $request->prepareRequestsForBatch();
        $facebookResponse = $this->sendRequest($request);

        return new FacebookBatchResponse($request, $facebookResponse);
    }
}
```

**6. FacebookResponse.php**

```html
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2014 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * You are hereby granted a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free license to
 * use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in source code or binary
 * form for use in connection with the web services and APIs provided by
 * Facebook.
 *
 * As with any software that integrates with the Facebook platform, your use
 * of this software is subject to the Facebook Developer Principles and
 * Policies [http://developers.facebook.com/policy/]. This copyright notice
 * shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
 * THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
 * DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */
namespace Facebook;

use Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNodeFactory;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

/**
 * Class FacebookResponse
 *
 * @package Facebook
 */
class FacebookResponse
{
    /**
     * @var int The HTTP status code response from Graph.
     */
    protected $httpStatusCode;

    /**
     * @var array The headers returned from Graph.
     */
    protected $headers;

    /**
     * @var string The raw body of the response from Graph.
     */
    protected $body;

    /**
     * @var array The decoded body of the Graph response.
     */
    protected $decodedBody = [];

    /**
     * @var FacebookRequest The original request that returned this response.
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var FacebookSDKException The exception thrown by this request.
     */
    protected $thrownException;

    /**
     * Creates a new Response entity.
     *
     * @param FacebookRequest $request
     * @param string|null     $body
     * @param int|null        $httpStatusCode
     * @param array|null      $headers
     */
    public function __construct(FacebookRequest $request, $body = null, $httpStatusCode = null, array $headers = [])
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->body = $body;
        $this->httpStatusCode = $httpStatusCode;
        $this->headers = $headers;

        $this->decodeBody();
    }

    /**
     * Return the original request that returned this response.
     *
     * @return FacebookRequest
     */
    public function getRequest()
    {
        return $this->request;
    }

    /**
     * Return the FacebookApp entity used for this response.
     *
     * @return FacebookApp
     */
    public function getApp()
    {
        return $this->request->getApp();
    }

    /**
     * Return the access token that was used for this response.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getAccessToken()
    {
        return $this->request->getAccessToken();
    }

    /**
     * Return the HTTP status code for this response.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getHttpStatusCode()
    {
        return $this->httpStatusCode;
    }

    /**
     * Return the HTTP headers for this response.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getHeaders()
    {
        return $this->headers;
    }

    /**
     * Return the raw body response.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

    /**
     * Return the decoded body response.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDecodedBody()
    {
        return $this->decodedBody;
    }

    /**
     * Get the app secret proof that was used for this response.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getAppSecretProof()
    {
        return $this->request->getAppSecretProof();
    }

    /**
     * Get the ETag associated with the response.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getETag()
    {
        return isset($this->headers['ETag']) ? $this->headers['ETag'] : null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the version of Graph that returned this response.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getGraphVersion()
    {
        return isset($this->headers['Facebook-API-Version']) ? $this->headers['Facebook-API-Version'] : null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if Graph returned an error message.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isError()
    {
        return isset($this->decodedBody['error']);
    }

    /**
     * Throws the exception.
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     */
    public function throwException()
    {
        throw $this->thrownException;
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates an exception to be thrown later.
     */
    public function makeException()
    {
        $this->thrownException = FacebookResponseException::create($this);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the exception that was thrown for this request.
     *
     * @return FacebookSDKException|null
     */
    public function getThrownException()
    {
        return $this->thrownException;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the raw response into an array if possible.
     *
     * Graph will return 2 types of responses:
     * - JSON(P)
     *    Most responses from Grpah are JSON(P)
     * - application/x-www-form-urlencoded key/value pairs
     *    Happens on the `/oauth/access_token` endpoint when exchanging
     *    a short-lived access token for a long-lived access token
     * - And sometimes nothing :/ but that'd be a bug.
     */
    public function decodeBody()
    {
        $this->decodedBody = json_decode($this->body, true);

        if ($this->decodedBody === null) {
            $this->decodedBody = [];
            parse_str($this->body, $this->decodedBody);
        } elseif (is_bool($this->decodedBody)) {
            // Backwards compatibility for Graph < 2.1.
            // Mimics 2.1 responses.
            // @TODO Remove this after Graph 2.0 is no longer supported
            $this->decodedBody = ['success' => $this->decodedBody];
        } elseif (is_numeric($this->decodedBody)) {
            $this->decodedBody = ['id' => $this->decodedBody];
        }

        if (!is_array($this->decodedBody)) {
            $this->decodedBody = [];
        }

        if ($this->isError()) {
            $this->makeException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate a new GraphObject from response.
     *
     * @param string|null $subclassName The GraphNode sub class to cast to.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphObject
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     *
     * @deprecated 5.0.0 getGraphObject() has been renamed to getGraphNode()
     * @todo v6: Remove this method
     */
    public function getGraphObject($subclassName = null)
    {
        return $this->getGraphNode($subclassName);
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate a new GraphNode from response.
     *
     * @param string|null $subclassName The GraphNode sub class to cast to.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     */
    public function getGraphNode($subclassName = null)
    {
        $factory = new GraphNodeFactory($this);

        return $factory->makeGraphNode($subclassName);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for creating a GraphAlbum collection.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphAlbum
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     */
    public function getGraphAlbum()
    {
        $factory = new GraphNodeFactory($this);

        return $factory->makeGraphAlbum();
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for creating a GraphPage collection.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphPage
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     */
    public function getGraphPage()
    {
        $factory = new GraphNodeFactory($this);

        return $factory->makeGraphPage();
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for creating a GraphSessionInfo collection.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphSessionInfo
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     */
    public function getGraphSessionInfo()
    {
        $factory = new GraphNodeFactory($this);

        return $factory->makeGraphSessionInfo();
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for creating a GraphUser collection.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     */
    public function getGraphUser()
    {
        $factory = new GraphNodeFactory($this);

        return $factory->makeGraphUser();
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for creating a GraphEvent collection.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphEvent
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     */
    public function getGraphEvent()
    {
        $factory = new GraphNodeFactory($this);

        return $factory->makeGraphEvent();
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for creating a GraphGroup collection.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphGroup
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     */
    public function getGraphGroup()
    {
        $factory = new GraphNodeFactory($this);

        return $factory->makeGraphGroup();
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate a new GraphList from response.
     *
     * @param string|null $subclassName The GraphNode sub class to cast list items to.
     * @param boolean     $auto_prefix  Toggle to auto-prefix the subclass name.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphList
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     *
     * @deprecated 5.0.0 getGraphList() has been renamed to getGraphEdge()
     * @todo v6: Remove this method
     */
    public function getGraphList($subclassName = null, $auto_prefix = true)
    {
        return $this->getGraphEdge($subclassName, $auto_prefix);
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate a new GraphEdge from response.
     *
     * @param string|null $subclassName The GraphNode sub class to cast list items to.
     * @param boolean     $auto_prefix  Toggle to auto-prefix the subclass name.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphEdge
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     */
    public function getGraphEdge($subclassName = null, $auto_prefix = true)
    {
        $factory = new GraphNodeFactory($this);

        return $factory->makeGraphEdge($subclassName, $auto_prefix);
    }
}
```

Please give me some tips how to solve that problem.

Comment: So your site is white screening? Sounds like you have an error. Check your logs first and foremost.

Comment: Yes the page is white screening. Actually all works fine in localhost, only on the proper server I have this issues. I think this issue related some how with facebook app settings changes what I made recently.

Comment: Maybe it is, maybe it isn't. Again, check your error logs, or turn on error reporting. Could be differences in e.g. version of PHP.

Comment: The erros i see is: 

Catchable fatal error: Argument 4 passed to Facebook\FacebookResponse::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/sportobatai/public_html/TOTASPORT/facebook-php-sdk/FacebookClient.php on line 225 and defined in /home/sportobatai/public_html/TOTASPORT/facebook-php-sdk/FacebookResponse.php on line 75

Now I need to figure how to fix it. Right now I don`t have an idea how to fix it :S

Comment: I’d start by specifying a halfway up-to-date API version - v2.2 was shut down a while ago.

Comment: As I understand the wise thing to do is upgrade from 2.2v to 2.12 version. I definitely will do that in the future, but my goal right now is to make a quick fix and make it work 

Answer (score 1):

if you using sdk facebook php, please make into method "getAccessToken()" the "redirect uri" valid, example:

```
<?php
...
$helper->getAccessToken('https://your-site.com/re-OAuth.php');
...
?>
```

where re-OAuth.php is is a return script.- (for example)

This will solve the problem .. greetings.-

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all who replied, your replies helped me to find a path to solve it. I have updated all facebook/php-graph-sdk files to 5.x version from https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk and that solved this error. So, case is closed.